# Using Azure Function .NET5 and HttpRequestData, how to handle file upload (form data)?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-5

The older Azure Function gives access to `HttpRequest`, which allows us to access the uploaded files via `req.Form.Files` etc.

The isolated .NET5 Azure Function uses `HttpRequestData` instead, which does not give access to the `Form`. How do I extract the uploaded files posted to the function?

Comment: There is no built-in support for multipart/form-data. Why? No idea. Seems Azure Functions for .NET5 was maybe a bit premature. You can piece together a solution from this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923811/net-5-azure-function-multipart-file-upload-issue).

Comment: @Andy Use `HttpMultipartParser.ParseAsync(req.Body)` can get files.

Comment: eh -- that's not maintained by Microsoft. That's a 3rd party. I don't know why you'd couple to a 3rd party that will lose interest in such a thing in probably 3 months. My comment still stands: It's not built-in... you have to implement it... *somehow*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add `<PackageReference Include="HttpMultipartParser" Version="5.0.0" />` in your .csproj file. And use `var parsedFormBody =  MultipartFormDataParser.ParseAsync(req.Body);`, you will get your files.

**In postman.**

[image]

**When debug**

[image]

## Below is my test code.

```
[Function("test")]
public static HttpResponseData Run1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext
        )
    {
        // get query params
        var testvalue=executionContext.BindingContext.BindingData["testparams"];
        // get form-body        
        var parsedFormBody =  MultipartFormDataParser.ParseAsync(req.Body);
        var file=parsedFormBody.Result.Files[0];

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Wow thank you for saving my full day struggle. Where can I find any related documentation on this? How else a new developer like me is supposed to figure something like this out!

Comment: @thankyoussd https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/366

Comment: I'm using the same approach but with larger PDF files my function host crashes withouth even calling the trigger. Any ideas?

Comment: @RainerSchuster I think there is a limit on the file size with functions especially for the Consumption tier.

Comment: 2 years later this is still best example