# POSTMAN alters the file contents when uploading it

Tags: c#, azure-functions, postman

I have a C# code that reads a Microsoft document file (.docx), and uploads it to Microsoft SharePoint (Office 365). The way that I read the file and stream is like the code snippet below:

```cs
using var stream = File.OpenRead("MyDocument.docx");
//And I upload the "stream" to Office 365 using Microsoft Graph API
```

The uploaded file to office 365 can successfully be opened in Microsoft Word. I wrapped the very same code piece that uploads files to Microsoft SharePoint in an Azure HTTP-triggered function and had POSTMAN submit the same file. The function looks like the following pattern:

```cs
    [Function(nameof(DocumentUploader))]
    public Task<HttpResponseData?> UploadAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = $"{nameof(DocumentUploader)}/{{filename}}/{{extension}}")]
        HttpRequestData request,
        string filename,
        string extension)
{
var stream = request.Body;
//The rest of the code to upload the stream to office 365 is the same
}
```

I realized that the length of `stream` or `request.Body` is greater than what `File.OpenRead(...)` yields. The consequence is that the uploaded stream to office 365 gets corrupted and it fails to open.

Any idea how to fix this problem to be able to upload the right content?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the request from Postman?

Comment: @phuzi Done, please see the updated question that now contains the screenshot.

Comment: _"I have a C# code that reads a Microsoft document file (.docx), and uploads it to Microsoft SharePoint (Office 365)"_ Could you show us the relevant bits of this code too?

Comment: @phuzi Please see the answer below. Fortunately POSTMAN does not exhibit any problem. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is per [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813786/using-azure-function-net5-and-httprequestdata-how-to-handle-file-upload-form). We need to use a 3rd party library to parse the request's body.